# Should I say I took the GCSE in 20XX or I sat for the GCSE in 20XX, any difference between the two?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-difference

I have just come across a video about IELTS, and it reminded me of GCSE.
I am wondering whether there are any differences in these two sentences:

> I sat for the GCSE in 2005.
>   I took the GCSE in 2005.

I want to know if there are other better ways of saying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCSE stands for General Certificate of Secondary Examination: it's the certificate that you get after you have taken the exam. If you say that you took a GCSE, people might think that you stole somebody else's certificate.

What you take, or sit for, is the exam:

> I sat for the GCSE exams in 2005
>
> I took the GCSE exams in 2005

According [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sit%20an%20exam%2Csit%20for%20an%20exam%2Ctake%20an%20exam&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csit%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csit%20for%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20an%20exam%3B%2Cc0), to "take an exam" is much more widely used than "sit for an exam" or "sit an exam".

Comment: I think "sit for" is more common in England... I very rarely hear people in the US say it.

Comment: @Catija, It's pretty old fashioned in England too.

Comment: Either is fine, but "I sat for the GCSE" sounds more formal, from my perspective.

Comment: Most people I know would say, "I did my GCSEs in 2005."  The fact that exams are involved is taken as read.

Comment: @ssav, GCSE is a proper noun: when you use a plural of a proper noun, it's assumed that you are talking about a number of [something else]- for example "Americans" really means "American people".  In this case, the [something else] is taken to be **exams**.